# Map filename with promise contents result

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I'm using bluebird for promises and I'm trying to get the contents for multiple files; what I want is to be able to get the contents for a file together with its filename, e.g:

`result = { 'file1.md': content }`

I've been trying something like this:

```
var files = [
    { filename: 'README.md', url: 'assetFiles/README.md' },
    { filename: 'CHANGELOG.md', url: 'assetFiles/CHANGELOG.md' },
    { filename: 'ISSUES_TEMPLATE.md', url: 'assetFiles/ISSUES_TEMPLATE.md' },
    { filename: 'PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md', url: 'assetFiles/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md' }];

  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    return [file.filename, fs.readFileAsync(file.url, 'utf-8')];
  }))
  .then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  };
```

however, what i'm getting from this is an array like:

`result = [ ['file1.md', Promise ], ... ];`

How can I get the filenames together with the contents of the file using bluebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having to create a new promise (the so-called "promise constructor anti-pattern"):

```
var result = Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
  return fs.readFileAsync(file.url, "utf-8")
    .then(data => [file.filename, data]);
});

result
  .then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

return result;
```

Comment: Logging the `.catch()` here will "eat" a rejection and not return it.

Comment: Thanks, tweaked to deal with that.

Comment: There is also `Promise.map` method.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't working because `Promise.all()` needs an array of promises, but you're passing it an array these `[data, promise]`.  As such, it doesn't know how to wait on all the individual promises.

Since you're using Bluebird, you can use [`Promise.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) directly.  It combines an array `.map()` iteration with `Promise.all()` for you automatically:

```
return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
  return fs.readFileAsync(file.url, "utf-8").then(data => [file.filename, data]);
});
```